# Design Property as Collection to handle input and output

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I am building a class object based on a XMLElement.  This element has some single occurence child elements but also has a couple of elements where there can be multiple occurences.

I read up on Indexer/Accessor usage on properties but when it comes to handling them for XML, i am coming at a loss.  Anyone have some further reading or direction as to design?

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Requirements of the multiple occurence elements:

1. Can have 0 to many occurences
2. Be able to access all or one of the occurences
3. Add/Remove/Edit an element based on index or item value (item value will be unique)

I dont want a hand-out but a hand-up.  Ultimately, the objective of this class is not be read from an XML file, initially, but instead instantiated and then exported out as an XML file.

Comment: You're creating a class that inherits from `XmlElement`? That's probably not the best approach.

Comment: the reason is i want to restrict the usage of the XmlElement object.  Its really nothing more than a mask over XmlElement with no other implementation outside of declarations: `public class UIElement:XmlElement` with a constructor `public UIElement(UIDocument doc, string name):base("", name, "", doc)` and yes UIDocument is a masking of XmlDocument.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution to this?  Have you checked out Linq-To-Xml (XElement, XDocument)?

Comment: Had to back burner this project, but plan on coming back to it and comment on the solution.  I think i got it solved just cant remember at the moment.